# International phone number validation regex issue in Laravel

Tags: php, regex, laravel, validation, laravel-6

This is my REGEX for the international phone number validation

```
\+(9[976]\d|8[987530]\d|6[987]\d|5[90]\d|42\d|3[875]\d|
                    2[98654321]\d|9[8543210]|8[6421]|6[6543210]|5[87654321]|
                    4[987654310]|3[9643210]|3[70]|7|1)\d{1,14}$
```

The above format validates all the numbers except, the international code for South Sudan which is +211 country code

Following is my complete validation rule for mobile number,

```
'mobile' => ['required', 'string','min:11','max:14', 'regex:/\+(9[976]\d|8[987530]\d|6[987]\d|5[90]\d|42\d|3[875]\d|
                    2[98654321]\d|9[8543210]|8[6421]|6[6543210]|5[87654321]|
                    4[987654310]|3[9643210]|3[70]|7|1)\d{1,14}$/'],
```

What I'm missing and is this a good international mobile number validation rule in Laravel?

Comment: `2[98654321]\d` handles `211` But it seems you have whitespace before it, so the regex engine will try to match that. You should have problems with the entire `2[98654321]\d` block as well as `4[987654310]` which will have the same problem.

Comment: nope, removed all the spaces still getting the  error message, The mobile format is invalid.

Comment: 'mobile' => ['required', 'string','min:11','max:14', 'regex:/\+(9[976]\d|8[987530]\d|6[987]\d|5[90]\d|42\d|3[875]\d|2[98654321]\d|9[8543210]|8[6421]|6[6543210]|5[87654321]|4[987654310]|3[9643210]|3[70]|7|1)\d{1,14}$/'],

Comment: What input are you testing this against?

Comment: @VLAZ +211770757180, which is automatically deduct the '+' mark

Comment: Well, [your regex should work](https://regex101.com/r/iKqcy7/1). Check for caching or something?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/210560/discussion-between-volka-dimitrev-and-vlaz).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I often use the [Laravel-Phone package](https://github.com/Propaganistas/Laravel-Phone) as this is, at least in my opinion, the cleanest way to validate and format phone numbers.

```
$request->validate([
    'phone' => [
        'required',
        Rule::phone()->detect()->country('GB'),
    ],
]);
```

To format a phone number, for example to have a consistent form to save to your database or to compare against, use

```
PhoneNumber::make('020 123456', 'GB')->formatE164(); // returns +4420123456
```

Comment: perfect,thanks for the advise